# How to change css properties with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```
var lights = ("blue", "white", "violet");

function check() {

for(var i = 0; i <= lights.length; i++) {
    if(i = "blue") {

  } else if (i = "white") {

  } else if (i = "violet") {

  }
}
```

I need help, I want to be able to change a css property which is not listed here but it consists of background colour is blue and I want to change it to another colour while accessing javascript. If anyone knows, please can they tell me step by step what to do please, thank you

Comment: 1) get the element 2) element.style

Comment: 1) Google [set CSS with JavaScript](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=set%20css%20with%20javascript) 2) You're welcome.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You need to post a more detailed question.

Comment: @hungerstar hahahahaha

Comment: Bonus tip #2 @dan08 your comparison is wrong, use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: Bonus tip #3: `i` is an number, not a string.

Comment: That whole code makes no sense, you mean. That array notation.

Comment: Bonus tip #4 `lights[i]` instead of `i` in the comparisons, thanks @JacobGray

Comment: You will need to be more detailed when asking questions in order to get a helpful answer. For instance, you've not included the css that you want to change, nor any html markup. Please revise your question accordingly.

Comment: `i = "blue"` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pure Javascript you can use something like this to set a background color for an element:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to change a CSS property of an element. Both methods require [accessing HTML DOM elements by ID or class](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp).

Classic Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('someID').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

jQuery:

```
$('#someID').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
```